# Apenas primeiro ID do form esta enviando!

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando enviar um post sem refresh com esse metodo abaixo mas só envia o primeiro form o segundo ele redireciona para pagina, estou com os forms dentro de um while PHP

```
$(function($) {
    $('#enviaadv').submit(function() {

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {
            if (!resposta){
                $onclick = showadv('bottom','left',resposta);
            }
            else
            {
                $onclick = showadv('bottom','left',resposta);
            }

        });

        return false;

    });
});
</script>   
<form id="enviaadv" action="functions/advogadoresponsavel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="advid" value='awdawd'>
    <input type="hidden" name="advnome" value='awdawd'>
    <input type="hidden" name="idunico" value='adawdaw'>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-link btn-just-icon btn-sm">
            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
        </button>
</form> 
<form id="enviaadv" action="functions/advogadoresponsavel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="advid" value='dawd'>
    <input type="hidden" name="advnome" value='awdawd'>
    <input type="hidden" name="idunico" value='awdawd'>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-link btn-just-icon btn-sm">
            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: IDs devem ser únicos!

Comment: eu preciso colocar o script dentro do while?

Comment: While? Faz menos sentido ainda, pois, não tem while no seu código. Se você quer "repetir um id", utilize `class` ao invés. De qualquer forma, é estranho ter dois forms.

Comment: assim funcionou http://prntscr.com/jwfd6l mas não tem algum método melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Deixe o script fora do laço e altere o seletor para `$('form').submit(function(){`... o form que for enviado será automaticamente capturado.

Comment: Mas eu não quero que pegue todos os forms da pagina apenas os uqe estão no laço

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro `FORM`:

`<input type="hidden" name="idunico" value='adawdaw'>`

Segundo `FORM`:

`<input type="hidden" name="idunico" value='awdawd'>`

Os ids são iguais. Tente realizar a troca do nome, como por exemplo, **`idunico2`**.